# unable to import db from azure, insufficient permissions

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Just starting messing with Windows Azure and i'm already running into troubles. From the manage page of my azure account, i went to the SQL Databases tab and then clicked on Import.
In the import page, i supplied my BACPAC url and created a new server and a new account (support).

I then tried to upload my db and recieved this error:

```
Error encountered during the service operation. 
Could not import package.
Warning SQL0: A project which specifies SQL Server 2012 as the target platform may experience compatibility issues with SQL Azure.
Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 15007, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 'support' is not a valid login or you do not have permission.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error. The executed script:
CREATE USER [support] FOR LOGIN [support];
```

Any ideas on what's wrong? I'm banging my head here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I just needed to [convert my sql 2012 db to sql azure](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/).